# How to store numbers of a string in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string `s="12345678"`

I need to store these numbers in a list like below format.

```
s=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
```

So can anybody help me how to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = "12345678"
a = [c for c in s]
```